# Why is Banshee not showing in sound menu in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, unity, banshee, indicator-sound

There is no entry for Banshee in the sound menu. Why is this? The "Sound Menu Integration" and "MPRIS D-Bus Interface" extensions are enabled.

Comment: I have MPRIS D-Bus enabled, but not the Sound Menu Integration.  Is it possible that having them both enabled causes some kind of conflict that makes neither work?

Comment: No without one of the other it WON'T work.

Answer (score 1):

The "sound menu integration" extension is not needed - not in my end at least, where banshee works perfectly from the sound menu.
Try disabling it.

Comment: I disabled that and it had no effect.